# How to pause face recognition based on condition and execute statements/function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, speech-recognition, face-recognition

I am running face recognition by following the wonderful tutorial [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/real-time-face-recognition-an-end-to-end-project-b738bb0f7348)

As soon as the unknown face detects and match the condition, I want to pause the face recognition and starts the speech recognition referring from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/voice-assistant-using-python/) statements to execute as shown in the code.

```
def gen(camera1):
    flag = 1
    while True:
        label, frame = camera1.get_frame()
        flag += 1
        if label=="unknown" and flag > 70:
            break
        else:
            yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'
            yield frame
            yield b'\r\n\r\n'
            yield label
    speak("What is your name ?") # only this executes.
    print("first") # not even this executes.
    query = takeCommand().lower()
    print("second")
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this task ?

Comment: Can you show us the ```speak()``` function?

Comment: ```def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait() ```

here it is. I have referred from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/voice-assistant-using-python/

Comment: Does it give you some error?

Comment: If the condition gets true, it breaks the loop and executes `speak("What is your name ?")` and freeze the cmd prompt.